# Why do I get "The Application Failed to initialize properly" when calling candle?

Tags: batch-file, wix

I am writing a batch script in which I need to run a candle command:

```
candle.exe - present in wix installation 'bin' directory
```

I have set the path during my batch file load to the wix installation directory, and have checked writing

```
 candle.exe abc.wxs -dplatform=x86 -ext WixUtilExtension
```

But on Windows XP it gives me an error:

> The Application Failed to initialize properly (0xc00001235)" .Click on OK To terminate

On Windows 7, candle.exe works fine.

How can I resolve this?

I guess it is because i have not specified as to how to deal with different OS

Comment: Maybe a 32/64 bit problem?

Comment: this is what i want to correct ; how do i set that the batch file would work for both 32 & 64 bit OS

Comment: You will need a 32bit version of your .exe

Comment: so how do i make candle.exe the 32-vit of windows

Answer (score 1):

This actually seems to be a result of not having .Net framework installed. Try installing .net 3.5 for Windows XP, or later for Windows 7 +.